# ImageWatch in Visual Studio 2013 : exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, windows-10

I currently work with OpenCV C++ in Visual Studion 2013 (Community). I have installed the plugin ImageWatch into Visual Studio, which is useful debugging aid.

After a recent upgrade of Windows 10 (I was already was working with Win 10 and it was fine), I started to receive the following error : "**exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation**" when opening ImageWatch from 'View/Other Windows/Image Watch'

I have tried un-/re-installing **ImageWatch** and updated VS 2013 to the latest .Net Version (5.0) for 2013. I also, as suggested on other posts, where the same error has been generated for different reasons, shortened the length/removed some of the lengthy less used System Environmental Variables. All to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the symptoms I received from Win 10 update were some missing .dll messages for MSVCP110.dll and MSVCR110.dll, generated directly after start up (of my PC).  A quick search indicated that I was missing some crucial Visual C++ Redistributable x64 and x86 updates for Visual Studio 2012.  (see http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr110dll-is/f052d325-3af9-4ae5-990b-b080799724db)

These can be download here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679#

After installing these updates for x64 and x86 and a reboot, the dll messages disappeared at start. Following a reinstallation of ImageWatch plugin, I no logner recieved the "exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" and Image Watch was opening and running fine.